# How to get a self written class, including dynamic Memory, to the Kernel and back?

Tags: cuda

i want to do light scattering simulations in 3D Objects with CUDA, its similar to raytracing. So i need a vector Class.

I tried to bring a Class, representing my Photons,to the Device. This Class includes a dynamic allocated vector class(self written). It is not realy necassary that it is dynamic, but i will have the same Problem in an other case.

The Problem is, that i get an **unspecified launch failure** if i try to modify the vector inside the Kernel.

I think it can also be a problem of copy constructors, or something. I didn´t programmed C++/CUDA for a while.

I use a GTX 480 with Compute capability 2.0 and CUDA 5.0.

**Here is my main:**

```
#include "photon.cuh"
#include "Container/vector3f.cu"

// Device code (Kernel, GPU)
__global__ void Sim(photon * l_x){
    l_x->vec->m_x = l_x->vec->m_x +1;
    l_x->vec->m_y = l_x->vec->m_y +1;
    l_x->vec->m_z = l_x->vec->m_z +1;
}

// Host Code (CPU)
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    photon *h_x,*d_x,*h_x2;

    h_x = new photon();
    //h_x->vec = new vector3f();
    h_x->vec->m_x = 1;
    h_x->vec->m_y = 2;
    h_x->vec->m_z = 3;

    std::cout << "Malloc" << std::endl;
    h_x2 = (photon*)malloc(sizeof(photon));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_x,sizeof(photon));

    std::cout << "Cpy h-d" << std::endl;
    cudaMemcpy(d_x,h_x,sizeof(photon),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaError_t Err = cudaGetLastError();
    if ( cudaSuccess != Err )
        std::cout << cudaGetErrorString (Err) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Sim" << std::endl;
    Sim<<<1, 1>>>(d_x);
    cudaThreadSynchronize();

    Err = cudaGetLastError();
    if ( cudaSuccess != Err )
        std::cout << cudaGetErrorString (Err) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "CPY back" << std::endl;
    cudaMemcpy(h_x2, d_x, sizeof(photon), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    std::cout << h_x2->vec->m_x << std::endl;
    std::cout << h_x2->vec->m_y << std::endl;
    std::cout << h_x2->vec->m_z << std::endl;

    cudaFree(d_x);
    return 0;
}
```

**The Photon Class:(.cuh)**

```
class photon {
public:
    vector3f *vec;
    __host__ __device__ photon();
    __host__ __device__ virtual ~photon();
    __host__ __device__ photon(const photon &other);
};
```

**(.cu)**

```
#include "photon.cuh"
#include "Container/vector3f.cu"

__host__ __device__ photon::photon(){
    this->vec = new vector3f();}

__host__ __device__ photon::~photon(){
    delete this->vec;}

__host__ __device__ photon::photon(const photon &rhs){
    this->vec = new vector3f(*rhs.vec);}
```

**And Finaly the vector Class:**

```
class vector3f {
public:
    float m_x;
    float m_y;
    float m_z;

__host__ __device__ vector3f(float l_x, float l_y, float l_z){
        this->m_x = l_x;
        this->m_y = l_y;
        this->m_z = l_z;}
__host__ __device__ vector3f(const vector3f& l_vector){
        this->m_x = l_vector.m_x;
        this->m_y = l_vector.m_y;
        this->m_z = l_vector.m_z;}
__host__ __device__ vector3f(){
        this->m_x = 0;
        this->m_y = 0;
        this->m_z = 0;}};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying problem is that the only time you instantiate your `photon` class anywhere is on the host, and you are copying that host instance directly to the device. That means that the device code is attempting to de-reference a host pointer on the GPU, which is illegal and produces the runtime error you are seeing. The CUDA APIs don't do any sort of magic deep copying, so you have to manage this yourself somehow.

The obvious solution is to redesign the `photon` class so that `vec` is stored by value rather than reference. Then the whole problem goes away (and the performance will be a lot better on the GPU because you remove a level of pointer indirection during memory access).

If you are fixated on having a pointer to `vec`, redesign the constructor so that it takes a pointer from a memory pool, and allocate a device pool for construction. If you pass a device pointer to the constructor, the resulting instance will have a pointer to valid device memory.